Why does `NoInfer` interfere with `Exclude` in Exclude<NoInfer<I>, undefined>`
type ExcludeUndefined<R> = Exclude<NoInfer<R>, undefined>;

let n1: ExcludeUndefined<number | undefined> = undefined;     // ok
let n2: ExcludeUndefined<Number | undefined> = undefined;     // not excluded
let s1: ExcludeUndefined<string | undefined> = undefined;     // ok
let s2: ExcludeUndefined<String | undefined> = undefined;     // not excluded
let d1: ExcludeUndefined<Date | undefined> = undefined;       // not excluded
let arr1: ExcludeUndefined<number[] | undefined> = undefined; // not excluded
let obj1: ExcludeUndefined<{} | undefined> = undefined;       // ok
let null1: ExcludeUndefined<null | undefined> = undefined;    // ok

Playground
Why is undefined still included in the type in some cases and sometimes it's not?

I expect this is a bug (or missing feature) in TS. NoInfer as implemented in ms/TS#56794 doesn't seem to distribute across unions, and it looks like it stays unresolved when there's an interface in the input type. No idea why. Someone (you?) should probably file a bug report and see what they say, and come back here with the answer.

Filed https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/60594
